# Bootstrap Carousel - Image too small

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap and the carousel plugin. This is my code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="active item"><img src="img/tree.jpg"></img></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Carousel nav -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

But the images are displayed too small. I want to fill it the whole carousel.

Here is an image (yes, the image is bigger than it is shown in the image):
[image]

Comment: Did it got resolved ? If not post a test page and I can surely help . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    ...
</div>
```

The question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590792/twitter-bootstrap-carousel-size)

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 3 add the responsive and center classes:

```
  <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="img/....jpg" alt="First slide">
```

I believe this is a duplicate question.