# twitter bootstrap carousel size

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, size, carousel

I'm creating a website for my dad using Twitter Bootstrap, it's done except for one thing: I can't figure out how to: 
- reduce the carousel width 
- center the carousel
- make scroll arrows still on image

[here is the website so you can check the source](http://ladesignbuild.net)

I've literally gone line by line through the css and adjusted every aspect of the carousel and then checked it in my browser.

Another point of confusion is that some of these adjustments have an effect if i test it in my browser with <kbd>SHIFT+CTRL+R</kbd> (so notepad++ opens it in google chrome directly from my desktop w/o using a server or host) and have seen some awkward changes, yet none of these changes carry over when I place them on the server.

I've seen some other posts suggesting adjustments to `.carousel` and `@image` and have tried those without success as well.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make scroll arrows still on image'.

Comment: You really need to optimise the images you're using in your carousel - they're way too large a file size to be user friendly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can just set the width of the carousel using CSS. Centering a block element is done with `margin: 0 auto`. Only change the CSS of `.carousel`, the rest is automatically styled correctly.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    ...
</div>
```

Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Et4pc/153/) to see it work.

Comment: Sorry, i meant make it so that the scroll arrows remain centered on the left and right side of the image, rather than on the left and right edge of the web page.

Thank you! Your solution worked perfectly! Now i just have to figure out what part of the carousel i messed up to make it scroll again.

Answer (score 8):

Simply add a class of 'container' onto the DIV with an ID of 'myCarousel'.

So this...

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
```

Becomes...

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container">
```

Comment: Thank you, Billy, you're right; will be reducing the image file size.